# Is there a different word that describes drawings and art in "cartoon" style, made for animation/illustration?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

The word cartoon evokes images of newspaper comics and amateurish drawings, possibly made by or for little kids. I'm looking for a synonym that describes more professional high quality art, think Disney/Pixar.

Alternatively, can you think of another related word that would be good to use in a name/logline of a website that teaches people how to professionally draw in Disney/Pixar style?

Comment: Are you thinking only of the current output of Disney which is largely, like Pixar, CGI; or are you thinking of the entire output of Disney from the 1920s onward? Most of the classic Disney pictures, and certainly those produced by Walt Disney himself, were pure animated cartoons. Every frame of the Mickey Mouse classics and other movies like Snow White was drawn and painted by a member of a huge team of animators. These people were highly skilled, highly organised and completely professional but they were producing cartoons. There's nothing inherently childish or amateurish about cartoons.

Comment: There’s the word sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Disney/Pixar "style" is referred to in common parlance as "CGI" - as initial sketches are heavily processed by computer programs, While "cartoon" evokes images of more simplistic images, any artwork which emphasizes heavy outlines to designate form and contour is called "**graphic**". (US)

Comment: Not convinced. These days CGI usually refers to scenes involving real actors against a green-screen backdrop.  Cartoons are rarely drawn by hand any more. They are usually computer-aided interactively not post-processed..

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - technically, I think the Pixar style is "CGI" but agree, 100% that when I hear CGI, I think of the layer of special effects added to live movies.

Answer (score 0):

"**animation**" is the word used in the industry.

Learn animation.

Learn to animate.

Learn to create animated scenes and movies.

etc.

Simply search online for *learn animation* - You will find plenty of [results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=learn+animation&atb=v245-3&ia=web&iai=ra-0&adx=shv1b&sexp=%7B%22prodexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22prdsdexp%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22biaexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22shv1%22%3A%22b%22%7D)

**Example**

> Learn 3D Animation Online The original online animation school taught
> by professional animators to grow you in the art of character
> animation. Your Mentor. Learn from our mentors who are professional
> animators working at major studios and are passionate about both
> teaching and your success.
>
> https://www.animationmentor.com/